# Set default navigation page to xaml in a library in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

My default page is in a library. How do I point this field to it?

[image]

Comment: Is that page on a project that is part of your solution?

Comment: @AndréMeneses Yes, it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the XML code of your WMAppManifest.xml and replace the property `NavigationPage` of the following line:

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" />
```

to:

```
{assemblyName};component/{pathToResource}
```

where the assemblyName is the name of the assembly of the page you want to navigate to, and pathToResource is the path (inside that project) to the page you want to navigate to.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently it worked without the first '/'. Like: {assemblyName};component/{pathToResource}.